# How to properly init/reset variables inside two nested while loops

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm having an issue on an assignment for school.
For whatever reason my outer while loop doesn't seem to affect anything. The solution just runs through the coin flips once, regardless of how many times I ask it to run through the sim.

```
simulations = int(input("How many times would you like to run the simulation? "))
cointosses = []
total_count = 0
total_seq = 0
# Invalid answer, system exit
if (not str(simulations)) or simulations <= 0:
      print("That is not a valid number of simulations")
      print("Shutting down")
      SystemExit

while simulations > 0:             
      while total_seq < 3:                   
            tosses = random.randint(1,2)       
            total_count += 1
            if tosses == 1:                    
                  cointosses.append("heads")
            if tosses == 2:                    
                  cointosses.append("tails")
            print(cointosses)                  
            seq_counter1 = 0
            seq_counter2 = 0
            check1 = "heads"
            check2 = "tails"
            for toss in cointosses:
                  if toss == check1:           
                        seq_counter1 += 1
                        seq_counter2 = 0
                        if seq_counter1 == 3:
                              total_seq = 3
                  if toss == check2:           
                        seq_counter1 = 0
                        seq_counter2 += 1
                        if seq_counter2 == 3:
                              total_seq = 3
      simulations -= 1
```

Comment: You dont have an exit condition as to when the loop should stop. Add a variable that will do a count of actual simulation that ran and use that in a while loop `sim_ran = 0    while sim_ran < simulations: ........ sim_ran +=1 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be carefull to init the variables at the proper place:
at the beginning of each simulations, counters and variables needs to be reseted,
so each simulation is not dependant on the others.

Here is the fixed code:

```
import random

simulations = int(input("How many times would you like to run the simulation? "))
check1 = "heads"
check2 = "tails"

# Invalid answer, system exit
if (not str(simulations)) or simulations <= 0:
      print("That is not a valid number of simulations")
      print("Shutting down")
      SystemExit


while simulations > 0:             
    total_seq = 0
    total_count = 0
    cointosses = []

    while total_seq < 3:
        tosses = random.randint(1,2)
        total_count += 1

        if tosses == 1:
            cointosses.append("heads")
        if tosses == 2:                    
            cointosses.append("tails")

        seq_counter1 = 0
        seq_counter2 = 0
        for toss in cointosses:
            if toss == check1:           
                seq_counter1 += 1
                seq_counter2 = 0
                if seq_counter1 == 3:
                    total_seq = 3
            if toss == check2:           
                seq_counter1 = 0
                seq_counter2 += 1
                if seq_counter2 == 3:
                    total_seq = 3
    print(cointosses)                  
    simulations -= 1
```

Example output:

```
How many times would you like to run the simulation? 4
['heads', 'heads', 'heads']
['heads', 'heads', 'heads']
['tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'heads']
```

Comment: This is great. I felt like I was close but couldn't figure out where I was wrong. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you check for `total_seq` in the inner loop. But the first run of the loop sets the `total_seq` to 3 and so no further simulations run.

to fix it:

```
while simulations > 0:
      total_seq = 0
      while total_seq < 3:
            # Your logic
      simulations -= 1
```